# Limit of Triggers total runtime Google Services

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, runtime

Can someone tell me ... Is it possible to increase the limit of  Triggers total runtime? More than 6 hours? Where can I to find out information about it?

Answer (score 0):

No. Otherwise there would be no point of the limits.